# Actionscript: SharedObject and addEventListener

Tags: actionscript-3

Could someone explain when does **local** SharedObject triggers event handlers added via addEventListener?

I have tried and it doesn't trigger, after flushing.

For example i have two object.swf both in separate browser tabs.

I'm adding data inside object.swf on one tab and want event to be triggered in object.swf from another tab.

Is it possible with native functionality and without remote type of SharedObject?

Ofc i could write infinite loop and check local storage for changes, but it's the last solution i would like to implement. :D

I was reading docs and played with example over there, but it doesn't trigger event, even if it is added before flushing.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only remote shared objects dispatch events.  If you want to communicate between two swfs, try LocalConnection instead. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks. I guess those two will do.